# MediaRecorder API chunks as an independent videos

Tags: webapi, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to build simple app that would stream video from camera using browser to the remote server.
For the camera access from browser I've found a wonderful `WebRTC API: getUserMedia`.

Now for the streaming it to the server IIUC the best way would be to use some of the `WebRTC_API` for transporting and then use some server side library to deal with it.

However, at first I went with a bit different approach:
I've user `MediaRecorder` based on the stream from camera. And then I was setting the timeslice for the `MediaRecorder.start()` to be few hundred Ms, e.g. 200. And I had some assumptions in wrt `MediaRecorder` which are not in sync with what I was observing:

**I've observed weird behaviour(wrt to my assumptions about `MediaRecorder`):**

1. If there was only 1 chunk uploaded to server -> it opens just fine.
2. If there are multiple chunks -> none of them loads correctly, they give errors: `Could not determine type of stream`. But then if I use `ffmpeg` to concat all the chunks - resulting file is fine. Same happens if I'm concatenating the `blobs` from `MediaRecorder.ondataavailable` on the client.

**Thus the question:**

Can the chunks in theory be independent video files? Or it is not what `MediaRecorder` was designed for? If it is not - then why do we even have the option to give `timeslice` parameter in its `start()` method?

**Bonus question**

If we're setting `timeslice` comparatively small, e.g. 10ms -> lots of data blobs that are sent to `MediaRecorder.ondataavailable` are of size 0. Where we can find some sort of guarantees/specs on the minimal `timeslice` that we can use, so that the data blobs are meaningful?

In the documentation there are the following:

> If timeslice is not undefined, then once a minimum of timeslice milliseconds of data have been collected, or some minimum time slice imposed by the UA, whichever is greater, start gathering data into a new Blob blob, and queue a task, using the DOM manipulation task source, that fires a blob event named dataavailable at recorder with blob.

So, my guess is that it is somehow related to some data blobs being of 0 size. What does it "some minimum time slice imposed by the UA" mean?

**PS**

Happy to provide code if needed. But the question is not about some specific code. It is to get understanding of the assumptions behind the `MediaRecorder API` and why they are there.

Answer (score 2):

The `timeslice` parameter does not allow to create independent media chunks; instead, it gives an opportunity to save data (e.g. on the filesystem, or uploaded to a server) on a regular basis, rather than holding potentially large media content in memory.